# Fibonacci java program

Tags: java, fibonacci

Created a program that would input a number and provides its equivalent fibonacci number as an output. But there's something wrong with my code :c

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Fibonacci {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        int prev, next, num, sum = 0, n;
        prev=next=1;

        System.out.print("Input number: ");
        num = in.nextInt();

        if ((num == 1) || (num ==2))
            System.out.println(prev);

        else {
            for( n=1; n<=prev; n++ ) {
                sum = prev + next;
                prev = next;
                next = sum;
            }

            System.out.println(sum);
        }

    }
}
```

Something's wrong I just can't see. Help? :c

Comment: "Wrong" is not clear, please explain what's wrong

Comment: What do you mean by "its equivalent fibonacci number"?

Comment: Time to learn how to use a `debugger`. Better to learn how to debug now before you start writing longer and more complex programs.

Comment: You might want to move this code into a method as well.  Not sure if you've been exposed to recursion yet, but that's the best (read: most concise) way to solve this problem.

Comment: Just to mention, as well as the [closed formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) `O(1)` version (subject to precision problems for large numbers, will require `BigDecimals` with a lot of decimal places for those), there are variations of the algorithm which costs `O(log(n))`[(java example)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15093963/664577).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your for loop to this:

```
for( n=2; n<num; n++ )
```

That'll solve your problem.

Explanation:
Since you've already determined that 1 or 2 will give you a 1, start your loop @ 2. Loop through until n becomes larger than the entered number. This will solve the problem you were having.

Comment: yeah, I have. I only went up to 10 places though.

Or am I misunderstanding the problem posted? I understood the problem to say: 1 is 1, 2 is 1, 3 is 2, 4 is 3, 5 is 8, 7 is 13, etc...

Comment: Thank you! :) It worked
btw 5 is 5 though. Not 8 :)

Comment: No problem, sometimes step away from the problem for a bit and draw it out to see what it should look like.

Edit: Yeah, sry, didn't mean 5 is 8... type (5 is 5)

Comment: i guess it's a typo cause there's no 6 :)

Comment: ZouZou - I think the problem here was Khelshy was looking for the say 5th number in the Fib sequence, which would be 5, the 6th number would be 8, etc

Comment: @Opzoleet Yes sorry! I misread this :) (actually the 5th number of the fib sequence is 3)

Comment: How did it became 3 ._. I'm pretty sure it's 5.

Answer (score 2):

You're stopping the loop when `n` reaches beyond `prev`, so you aren't getting the correct number.  Stop it when you've passed `num` instead:

```
for(n = 1; n <= num; n++) {
```

Example run:

```
Input number: 6
21
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the fiboniki number times the user has given input then you need to iterate in `for` loop.

```
 for( n=1; n<=num; n++ ) {
                    sum = prev + next;
                    prev = next;
                    next = sum;
                    System.out.println(sum);
                }
```

Also to print the number you need to put it in the loop.

Comment: Instead of doing homework for people, why not explain the process of working through the problem and debugging code?

Comment: kk sir @KevinWorkman.It will be better if you wait for some time before downvote the answer